# Swift playground timeline doesn't always show?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-playground

Alright, I have been working in Swift playgrounds and the project I am making is very visual, hence I need the timeline to display/interact with it.

My code all compiles fine and I have Xcode set to manual run, however when I open Xcode sometimes I have to quit Xcode and open again for the timeline to populate. It will just keep spinning saying it is "running" and not show anything.

Is there a way to fix/improve this? All my real classes are in resources and fps is excellent once going